# Binding webview navigation actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have webview and a Go-Back button for webview.
I need two functionality from Go-back button(as in standard browser)

1. Button should be disabled when it is not possible to go back
2. When pressed, should go back

Disabling the button is achieved by cocoa binding.

And go back action is done by binding following selector from Owner class

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [_webView goBack];
}
```

Since the `buttonPressed:` selector is only calling goBack selector, can I bind `self.webView.goback` to the button, eliminating the need of buttonPressed selector in owner class.

Comment: No that's not possible. It is required to get called through custom event only, like you are doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code Disabling your button

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;{

 if ([webView canGoBack]) {
  _button.enabled = NO;  
 }else{
   _button.enabled = YES;
 }

}
```

Comment: Consider your answer as a question, and my question as your answer. You would start loving your life..

Comment: his answer should have been: no you can't. but this is cool code to only enable/disable contextually. Nice of you to vote him down for his effort. typical SO behavior.  j/s